# How can I get struct char[] field value use DllImport function?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

In DLL struct is:

```
typedef struct tagEKIDinfo{
    short usbNo;   
    short printerID;   
    CHAR  serialNo[6];   
    WORD  mediaType;   
} EKIDinfo, *PEKIDinfo;
```

In C# :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct EKIDinfo
{
    public int usbNo;
    public int printerID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string serialNo;
    public ushort mediaType;
}
```

And the function is:

DLL:

```
DWORD WINAPI EKSearchPrinters( PEKIDinfo pIDInfo, DWORD infoSize, LPDWORD pSizeNeeded, LPDWORD pinfoNum )
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("EKUSB.dll", EntryPoint = "EKSearchPrinters", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int EKSearchPrinters(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 infoSize, ref Int32 pSizeNeeded, ref Int32 pNumber);
```

The serialNo true value is "218699", but I got "99?" with C#.

Why about this? Can anyone help me? Thans a lot!

Comment: does it relate to C and C++ at all?

Comment: `Pack = 1`... are you sure that's right?  The [default for Win32 is 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296569(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: @SamAxe I tried, but not working, it seems that had nothing different result with 1 and 8 or eles or empty.

Comment: @SurajRao yes. c++ I gues, I just has this dll and pdf document about this dll function structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a guess, but if you're off by four bytes, maybe the first two fields are too big?  Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct EKIDinfo
{
    public System.Int16 usbNo;      //<--- changed
    public System.Int16 printerID;  //<--- changed
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string serialNo;
    public ushort mediaType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got wrong types. DLL interface says

```
struct tagEKIDinfo {
     short usbNo;       <- short (2 bytes), not int (4bytes)
     short printerID;   <- short (2 bytes), not int (4bytes)
     CHAR  serialNo[6];   
     WORD  mediaType;   
 }
```

Note the `short`. This is likely to be `int16` on C# side, not `int` as you have now. Since there are 2 such fields, all before char-array, 2x(4-2)=4 and that would account exactly to the `218699`->`99` = 4 chars missing

Comment: :) I checked the document and yes, the field is short, works great, that is my wrong~ !

Answer (score 0):

The struct is declared incorrectly. The first two members should be `short`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct EKIDinfo
{
    public short usbNo;
    public short printerID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string serialNo;
    public ushort mediaType;
}
```

Rather than manually marshal the struct I'd pass it by reference.

```
[DllImport("EKUSB.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern uint EKSearchPrinters(
    ref EKIDinfo pIDInfo,
    uint infoSize, 
    ref uint pSizeNeeded,
    ref uint pNumber
);
```

I'm not sure why you named the first parameter to suggest a handle, but it certainly doesn't look like one to me.

It's entirely possible that some of the `ref` parameters should be `out` depending on the data flow intent which has not been shown.

The other potential issue is how you call the function. You didn't show the call or any details of how it must be done.